# Libgdx what is the use of triangles on polygonregion?

Tags: java, libgdx

While using PolygonRegion why we need "short[] triangles"?
What is the use of this?
`PolygonRegion(TextureRegion region, float[] vertices, short[] triangles)`

Comment: Each set of three consecutive items in the short array are indices in the vertices array that form a triangle.